# Possibilities to calculate process working time in Java

Tags: java, time, process

Is there any possibility to count the working time of a processes in java?

for example in a pseudo code

```
for(some Object:all Objects){
startProcess1();
....
startProcessn();}
if(startProcess1 is finished){
getTimeOfProcessOne()}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Processing time of a thread/objects in java can be determined as

```
ThreadMXBean bean=ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long id=Thread.currentThread().getId();
long start,end;
if(!bean.isThreadCpuTimeSupported()){System.exit(0);}
start=bean.getThreadCpuTime(id);

//Call some methods , process some objects

end=bean.getThreadCpuTime(id)-start;
```

Now `end` will contain processing time of `Thread` with ID as `id`.
This time will be in NanoSeconds.